# Prevent user from entering a float number, greater than 3 decimals

Tags: javascript, validation, reactjs, precision, decimal-point

I have an input field using react with this code:

```
const InputField = props => (
  <div className="input-row">
    <input
      {...props.input}
      type={props.type}
      className="form-control input-box__input"
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      value={props.value}
      defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
      defaultChecked={props.defaultChecked}
      disabled={props.disabled}
      onChange={props.onChange}
      checked={props.checked}
    />
    {props.meta.touched && props.meta.error &&
    <span className="error">
        {props.intl.formatMessage({ id: props.meta.error }) }
      </span>}
  </div>
);
```

I want to add a `validation` or better a `preventDefault` property so that it won't let the user entering a floating number with more than three decimal points.

If the user enter a number like this: 1.234 it should prevent the user for entering more numbers despite typing on his keyboard. Any ideas as to how to implement this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please don't expect us to write your code for you. Hint: I would convert the pure functional component into a class component and use an `onKeyDown` handler method to validate the currently entered value.

Comment: I never say to write the code for me. It's mandatory for my project to use stateless components with containers.

Comment: Try `input type="number"` you can controll the input size via the [step attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number). This will work on a browser level though only with those browser which support this HTML element. But why would you want to prevent the user from a specific number? The float will be translated to 32bit anyway

Comment: It's a required validation. I must not let the user entering a number with greater than three decimal points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like someone else suggested, use the onKeyDown event to limit the input. Quick and dirty example: https://jsfiddle.net/bv9d3bwk/2/

```
const InputField = props => (
  <div className="input-row">
    <input
      {...props.input}
      type={props.type}
      className="form-control input-box__input"
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      value={props.value}
      defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
      defaultChecked={props.defaultChecked}
      disabled={props.disabled}
      onChange={props.onChange}
      onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}
      checked={props.checked}
    />
    {props.meta.touched && props.meta.error &&
    <span className="error">
        {props.intl.formatMessage({ id: props.meta.error }) }
      </span>}
  </div>
);

const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    const decimal_index = e.target.value.indexOf('.');
    if(decimal_index > -1){
        var decimals = e.target.value.substring(decimal_index, e.target.value.length+1);
        if(decimals.length > 4 && e.keyCode !== 8){
           e.preventDefault();
        }
        //this.props.onChange();
    }
}
```

Comment: I accept it as an answer but i'ts not absolutely correct. When a user enter a non decimal number it prevents him from entering more digits.

Comment: Ah okay, updated the fiddle to allow any amount of numbers before the decimal. https://jsfiddle.net/bv9d3bwk/1/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :)

Comment: I want to ask one more question. Your solution is nearly perfect except from one thing:When the user enters a price with more than 3 decimals the system limits him to 3 decimals, but he switches the last digit with the last presses digit. For example the user types .0.562. When he types digit 3 after that, the system replaces the 2 with the 3. this is not correct, the user must delete the previous digit if he wants to replace it.

Comment: @user7334203 After looking at my jsfiddle, I'm not sure what I was thinking! lol I updated the fiddle to just prevent them from entering anything once they reach the max. https://jsfiddle.net/bv9d3bwk/2/

Comment: Updated. https://jsfiddle.net/bv9d3bwk/3/. For future changes, you can just check the keycode and allow whatever you want through (enter key).

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks a lot!!